# Windows App to Keep Num Lock On

Tags: windows

Whenever I remote desktop to a machine, it seems NumLock is turned off. I never ever want NumLock off. Is there a windows app which will monitor the numlock state and turn it back on if it is off?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[**NumLocker**](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/NumLocker.shtml) is a lightweight and useful **freeware** designed to **lock the state of Caps Lock, Num Lock and Scroll Lock keys**. You can force these keys to "Always On" and "Always Off". With NumLocker, you can prevent accidental pressing and changing state of these keys.

[image]

Comment: do note that numlocker disables the keys entirely, I know there are other programs that do the same but make the key pressable (detectable in games), though unfortunately I forgot which programs can do that

Answer (score -2):

Try the Registry Editor:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154529/EN-US

To enable Num Lock before a user logs on, follow these steps:

1. Run Registry Editor.
2. Move to 
   `HKEY_USERS\.Default\Control Panel\Keyboard`
3. Change the value for `InitialKeyboardIndicators` from `0` to `2`.

There are other methods built into Windows you can explore to keep
that darn light always on!

Comment: please don't use language like that in your posts.

Comment: The original language was bad enough, but the worse problem with this answer is that it does not in any way answer the question. The question of how to KEEP the number lock on comes up frequently (it's an irritation that Microsoft SHOULD address but won't) and I am amazed and annoyed in equal measure about how many answers talk about how to have number lock on AT STARTUP, when that was exactly NOT the question asked. That's yet again what this one is doing. I'm surprised that it doesn't have down votes.