# How to make Numeric keypad keys always enter digits in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard

How to get in Windows the equivalent of this linux function:

```
setxkbmap -option numpad:mac
```

From the docs:

> numpad:mac           Numeric keypad keys always enter digits (as in
> Mac OS)

This means regardless if pressing the NumLock key and regardless of the NumLock LED state, the keypad always enters digits, not cursor movement.

The closest thing I found for Windows is turning off the NumLock key (with apps or directly using the registry entry Keyboard Layout/"Scancode Map"), but that just gives the state as if I never press the NumLock key. The numpad mode can be still changed by software, inherited from BIOS on startup etc.

As a "bonus", I would also like to turn off the LED.

So: LED off, keys enter digits, always

Comment: I'm not sure that is matters, but just in case, can you provide the make and model of the machine?

Comment: Lenovo P53 (laptop)

Comment: Did you already check out and see.... [`HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard` -> `InitialKeyboardIndicators` to "`2`", and after reboot, the Num is locked now. This remains also after pressing the Win button, but only after 2nd reboot! (After 1st reboot, the WIN botton unlocked the NUM button...)](https://forums.lenovo.com/topic/view/1438/1443451). Does BIOS not have a settings to set it to always on as well so firmware level and OS level are both set to the default on value.

Comment: Page 2 of that post lists "Basicly you go to ``HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard\``  and there you change "`InitialKeyboardIndicators`" to `2` as well stating it works for Windows 10 so it might be worth a shot as well." Might even be worth doing a search on the registry for "InitialKeyboardIndicators" and seeing if it'd be worth changing those to the other value of  `2` as well.

Comment: This seems related: https://superuser.com/questions/248880/windows-app-to-keep-num-lock-on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted similar behavior, and used `HKLM\...\Keyboard Layout\ScanCodeMap` to map the scancodes for the top-row number keys to the numeric keypad keys as the top-row keys are immune to the state of `NumLock`. That remap is contained in this `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"ScanCode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,0c,00,00,00,02,00,4f,00,03,00,\
  50,00,04,00,51,00,05,00,4b,00,06,00,4c,00,07,00,4d,00,08,00,47,00,09,00,48,\
  00,0a,00,49,00,0b,00,52,00,34,00,53,00,00,00,00,00
```

With this remap, the state of `NumLock` makes no difference, nor does `CapsLock`, but if you're holding down the `Shift` key, you will get the symbols associated with the top-row keys.

If you turn off `NumLock` via `InitialKeyboardIndicators`, you can include mapping a *`Null`* scancode to the `NumLock` key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"ScanCode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,0d,00,00,00,02,00,4f,00,03,00,\
  50,00,04,00,51,00,05,00,4b,00,06,00,4c,00,07,00,4d,00,08,00,47,00,09,00,48,\
  00,0a,00,49,00,0b,00,52,00,34,00,53,00,00,e0,45,e0,00,00,00,00
```

And that *should* prevent the indicator light from coming on when the  `NumLock` key is pressed. (No indicator light here, so can't test). It could probably still be turned on by software, but this should cover "normal" circumsstance.

### After merging either of the above `.reg` files, logout/login or restart for changes to take effect

---

### Aside:

The `ScanCodeMap` values were created by this **PowerShell** script. It allows (relatively) easy editing of the scancode arrays to add and delete remappings as desired. Because it's editing the `HKLM` hive, you have to have `Admin` permissions and run the scfipt from an *Admin* **PowerShell** console.

```
##############################################################
$SimplePairs = @(
 0x02, 0x4f # 1 ! > 1 end
 0x03, 0x50 # 2 @ > 2 ↓
 0x04, 0x51 # 3 # > 3 pg dn
 0x05, 0x4b # 4 $ > 4 ←
 0x06, 0x4c # 5 % > 5
 0x07, 0x4d # 6 ^ > 6 →
 0x08, 0x47 # 7 & > 7 home 
 0x09, 0x48 # 8 * > 8 ↑
 0x0a, 0x49 # 9 ( > 9 pg up
 0x0b, 0x52 # 0 ) > 0 Ins
 0x34, 0x53 # . > > . Del
# 0x00, 0x3a # Null > CapsLock
)
$ExtendedPairs = @(
 0x00, 0xe0, 0x45, 0xe0 # Null > NumLock(0xe045)
)
$ByteCount = 2 * $SimplePairs.Length + $ExtendedPairs.Length + 16
$Remap = New-Object -TypeName byte[] -ArgumentList $ByteCount
$Remap.Length
$Remap[8] = $SimplePairs.Length/2 + $ExtendedPairs.Length/4 + 1
For ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $SimplePairs.Length ; $i += 2) {
   $Remap[$i * 2 + 12] = $SimplePairs[$i]
   $Remap[$i * 2 + 14] = $SimplePairs[$i + 1]
}
For ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $ExtendedPairs.Length ; $i += 4) {
   $Offset = $SimplePairs.Length * 2
   $Remap[$i + 12 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i]
   $Remap[$i + 13 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i + 1]
   $Remap[$i + 14 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i + 2]
   $Remap[$i + 15 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i + 3]
}
$Splat = @{
    Path  = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout'
    Name  = 'ScanCode Map'
    Value = $Remap
    Force = $True
}

$Splat['Value'] | format-hex

New-ItemProperty @Splat
```

Comment: Did you test it? The state of nunlock has no effect once the keys are re-mapped. So worst case scenario, NumLock is turned on and the LED lights up; but the keys still type numbers.

Comment: You seem to be working from the mistaken assumption that `NumLock` is tied to the physical keys of the numeric keypad. It is not. It is tied to their `default scancodes`. No physical keys will generate those scancodes after the re-map.  The state of `NumLock` has no effect on the top-row keys, and will thus have no effect on any key that generates those same scancodes (specifically, the re-mapped keypad keys). So, once again, slowly...: The state of `NumLock` is immaterial if no keys generate scancodes that are effected by `NumLock`.

Comment: I understand that perfectly. Now tell me what effect NumLock has on the top-row numerical keys??? What effect does it have on `A` - `Z` keys??? NONE!!! I'm beginning to doubt whether your comments stem from an honest misunderstanding or if you're so desparate for the bounty that you're trying to convince the OP that my solution is invalid before trying it.

Comment: Mutual,I'm sure...

Comment: @harrymc now I am frustrated, and will try to explain: whether numlock is on or off, the keys in the top row still type numbers. This answer remaps the keys in the numpad so that they appear to the OS as if they were coming from the top row. Therefore, the state of numlock does not affect them at all.

Comment: Thanks, works great. For completeness, please add a note that a logout/login (or reboot) is required for the registry change to make effect.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for accepting my answer and the bounty! :D

Answer (score 0):

Meet the
[NumLock Enforcer](https://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=9018.msg66572#msg66572),
written by a donation-coder moderator with the moniker "lanux128".

This is a [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script that will
force your NumLock to always be On, no matter if some program has
set it to Off.
It accomplishes this by checking its state every 500 milliseconds.

This is the script (note that the semi-colon starts a comment):

```
; NumLock Enforcer
; To monitor and switch on the NumLock key
; Date: 01/07/2007  ;Last Updated: 01/07/2007
; Refer: hxxp://www.donationcoder.com/Forums/bb/index.php?topic=9018
; Changes since:
; ***** 
;
#SingleInstance force
;#NoTrayIcon  ;if you don't need a tray icon
#InstallKeybdHook
#Persistent

;Menu, tray, Icon, %A_WinDir%\System32\shell32.dll, 105
appname=NumLock Enforcer
SetTimer, EnforceNumLock, 500
Return

EnforceNumLock:
   NumLockStatus := GetKeyState("Numlock", "T")
    IfEqual, NumLockStatus, 0
      {
      SetNumLockState, On
      ;Uncomment the below line if you want some kind of feedback.
      ;TrayTip,%appname%,NumLock Status = On,,1
      }
Return

;Win+p pauses the script,just in case you need the NumLock.
#p::Pause

;Win+q exits...
#q::ExitApp
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a file named
`NumLock Enforcer.ahk` and double-click it to test.
You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: Just out of academic curiosity, how much of a system's resources would be consumed by a script that polls constantly such as this one?  It'd probably be difficult to answer objectively, but for sake of example, roughly how many of these could you run in background before there's a noticeable impact to performance on a mid/high-end  ($2.5k) build?

Comment: @Arctiic: A lot. One API call to check the key status twice a second is nothing. Windows does much more even when the computer is "idle".